# What disassembler mean by RtlIsZeroMemory?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, assembly, disassembly

A Windows Qt C++ application is crashing sometimes, it seems to be happening more often on slower machines.
On my main development machine (macbook pro 2019 running windows on bootcamp) it almost never happen.
But on another latptop, a 8GB ram, intel core i5 1.60GHz, it happens pretty much always.
So much I replicated the development environment there to run the Qt Creator project in debug mode.
Then I got the following picture

[image]

What is the disassembler telling?

```
Disassembler (RtlIsZeroMemory)
```

How can I further debug this?

Comment: Your program is currently executing [RtlIsZeroMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddk/nf-ntddk-rtliszeromemory). The stack trace is more interesting and indicates crashing on freeing memory due to heap corruption

Comment: Where exactly do you read that "crashing on freeing memory due to heap corruption"? May I ask what are the most common causes of heap corruption?

Comment: Buffer overflows generally

Comment: Likelihood of such programming errors manifesting as crashes is always bigger in tight conditions. Unfortunately the MinGW gcc (that QtCreator by default targets on Windows) does not have much support for catching causes of memory corruption. The clang and msvc are better for that. Hunting bugs is most challenging part of our work, so learn to enjoy the challenge.

Comment: I'm actually using msvc compiler. Appreciate if you could point which features MinGW is lacking. Since I would usually default to use it unless there is a specific requirement.

Comment: Mostly likely you're trying to free a memory that was already released (i.e. dangling pointer). Are you, by any chance, using QSharedPointer for QObject-derived classes which has specified the parent object?